# Detecting superquadratic shapes

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I have implemented a parametric model to detect shapes using superquadrics. I am able to recover simple shapes like planes, circles, cylinders, and spheres.

If my point-cloud consists of an object like a stapler, is it possible to represent this shape using Superquadrics or do I need to segment each individual part of the superquadric and recover the shape?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very large topic, and an old one too. I don't believe anyone in the academic community seriously works on 3D modeling using superquadrics/superellipsoids any longer.

Yes, it requires part segmentation, which is quite tricky and usually requires fusion of multiple views.

When it was an active field of research one, some of the best published results I am aware of were produced in [Frank Ferrie's lab at CIM - McGill University](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~apl/publi.html) in the early '90s. See, in particular, Lejeune's [paper](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~mrl/pubs/ferrie/lejeune-partitioning.pdf) on partitioning, [Whaite's ones](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.21.1397&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on sequential modeling, [my own work](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.4778&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on active recognition.